# Console Program closing itself for no reason before code has finished

Tags: c#, console, console-application

My console application exits before code has finished (after executing/trying to execute lines such as "Console.WriteLine" or "int i = 0")

I've added some breakpoints to see which line is the last to be executed before the program exits. On the first few attempts, the program exits after/when trying to execute the following line:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Online users to chat with ({users.Length} total):");
```

Then, I tried to get the value of the string in the Console.WriteLine brackets using the Immediate window- which worked. I pressed F10 to proceed to the next line, and it did- successfully printing the given parameter. But then, after pressing F10 the program closed itself, when the highlighted part was "int i = 0":

```
for (int i = 0; i < users.Length; i++)
```

Here is the code, I've added comments on all the lines the program closed so far:

```
public static void Main()
    {
        client = new WebClient();
        messages = null;

        try
        {
            LocalhostServer.Start("Chat");
            // Starts a server with System.Net.HttpListener. The prefix added is: http://localhost:<port>/Chat/
        }
        catch { }
        LocalhostServer.RecievedRequest += LocalhostServer_RecievedRequest;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your name:");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        // closed here^^ after adding a new breakpoint to this line, makes no sense to me
        try
        {
            client.DownloadString(new Uri(Url + "AddUser?name=" + name));
            // Url is a static string which is set to: "http://localhost:<port>/Chat/"
        }
        catch { }

        ShowOnlineUsers();
    }

    private static async void ShowOnlineUsers()
    {
        try
        {
            thread = new Thread(CheckIfChatStarted);
            thread.Start();

            Console.Clear();
            string[] users = (await DownloadStringUntilSuccess(Url + "GetOnlineUsers")).Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            // closed here^^ after adding a new breakpoint to this line

            Console.WriteLine($"Online users to chat with ({users.Length} total):"); // closed here
            for (int i = 0; i < users.Length; i++) // closed here on "int i = 0;"
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}. {users[i]}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter user number to chat with:");
            recipient = users[int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) - 1];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { // hasn't reached the breakpoint on that bracket

        }

        client.DownloadString(new Uri(Url + "StartChat?name=" + name + "&recipient=" + recipient));
    }
```

I have no idea why it happens... Many thanks in advance to anyone's attempt to help!

**P.S- Can this be caused due to a Console.Clear/Console.WriteLine commands being executed in a background thread while the main thread is waiting for user's input (Console.ReadLine)? If so, is there any solution/work-around?**

Comment: Surround all that with try/catch and output exception message. Also put a breakpoint into the catch clause. I am confident you are swallowing an exception.

Comment: Also, if you could perhaps add the entire `main()` method? It would help, as currently I don't see where `users` comes from.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to SO!

Comment: @ZivB do you have any `async` calls in the method? How is `users` initialized and populated?

Comment: You haven't shown any code that would cause the problem you've described. Please post a small sample (doesn't have to be *all* your code) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments! I've edited my post to include more information and a possible cause for the problem (which would be a real pain if it actually is the issue)

Comment: @ZivB Should there not be an `await` before you call `ShowOnlineUsers();`? It is an async method and you are not awaiting it...not sure if that's the issue, but it is one. Modify ShowOnlineUsers to return a Task and await it. Give that a shot and post back please.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a

```
Console.Readline()
```

To hold the Console open...

Comment: I think he already has, with this line `recipient = users[int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) - 1];`